# Unable to upload different extension file to the web server

Tags: java, http, network-programming, content-type, httpurlconnection

I always get exception: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: for extensions other than txt. 
   Here is my code

```
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(filepath);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

for(int readnum; (readnum = fis.read(buf)) != -1; )
{
 bos.write(buf,0,readnum);
 System.out.println("read"+ readnum+ "bytes");  

}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
String filemsg = new String(bytes,"cp1252");
filemsg = URLEncoder.encode(filemsg,"UTF-8");
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
 //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;    boundary=**************");         
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/html;charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(filemsg.length()));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");   
connection.setRequestProperty("method","setmsg");
connection.setRequestProperty("sender",sender);
connection.setRequestProperty("recipent",recipent);
connection.setRequestProperty("msg",tf.getText());
connection.setRequestProperty("time",time.format(cal.getTime()));
connection.setRequestProperty("hms",hms.format(cal.getTime()));
connection.setRequestProperty("file",filemsg);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(" ");
wr.flush ();
wr.close ();   

tf.setText("");
is = connection.getInputStream();
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
response = new StringBuffer(); 
while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
{
  response.append(line);
  response.append('\r');
}
System.out.println(response.toString());
rd.close();
tf.setText(""); 
tf.requestFocus(true);
}
```

I am trying to send a .wav file to a webserver but i am getting this exception as response from the server. The code works just fine for any .txt or even zipped(.rar) form of a .txt file. I guess the "content-type" part is having some problem but I am not sure...Thanks for helping.

Comment: There are plenty of HTTP APIs which don't require you to do this sort of low-level coding - and will hopefully avoid the way you're currently butchering your binary data. I suggest you use one of them - look into the Apache HTTP Client libraries, for example.

Comment: please post the exact error message

Comment: Actually this module is part of my college project and due to this i cant use third party API for this stuff....i need to figure out a way to upload other extension files using this method only...thank you for the suggestion